# Why would a service that works locally be getting kill signals frequently in docker?

Tags: docker, webpack, kubernetes, pm2, minikube

I have a universal react app hosted in a docker container in a minikube (kubernetes) dev environment. I use virtualbox and I actually have more microservices on this vm.

In this react app, I use `pm2` to restart my app on changes to server code, and `webpack hmr` to hot-reload client code on changes to client code.

Every say 15-45 seconds, `pm2` is logging the below message to me indicating that the app exited due to a `SIGKILL`.

```
App [development] with id [0] and pid [299], exited with code [0] via signal [SIGKILL]
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why it is happening. It is relatively frequent, but not so frequent that it happens every second. It's quite annoying because each time it happens, my webpack bundle has to recompile.

What are some reasons why `pm2` might receive a SIGKILL in this type of dev environment? Also, what are some possible ways of debugging this?

I noticed that my services that use pm2 to restart on server changes do NOT have this problem when they are just backend services. I.e. when they don't have `webpack`. In addition, I don't see these SIGKILL problems in my prod version of the app. That suggests to me there is some problem with the combination of webpack hmr setup, pm2, and minikube / docker.

I've tried the app locally (not in docker /minikube) and it works fine without any sigkills, so it can't be webpack hmr on its own. Does kubernetes kill services that use a lot of memory? (Maybe it thinks my app is using a lot of memory). If that's not the case, what might  be some reasons kubernetes or docker send SIGKILL? Is there any way to debug this?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what is the output of `kubectl get events` from the namespace your pod is running in? It might be worth running `kubectl get events --watch` while this happens, if it's relatively frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite tell from the error message you posted, but usually this is a result of the kernel OOM Killer (Out of Memory Killer) taking out your process. This can be either because your process is just using up too much memory, or you have a cgroup setting on your container that is overly aggressive and causing it to get killed. You may also have under-allocated memory to your VirtualBox instance.

Normally you'll see Docker reporting that the container exited with code 137 in `docker ps -a`

`dmesg` or your syslogs on the node in question may show the kernel OOM killer output.

Comment: you were spot on. Using dmesg I was able to see it was oom-killer that killed the process. Now to debug the thing causing OOM which I have a hunch. TY for your suggestion!